# What is the most canonical way to install Numpy, Scipy, Pandas?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to install Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, and sklearn.
I downloaded Numpy and Scipy individually from their websites, but Scipy warns not to install manually, and when I try to install Numpy I get an error 'could not locate executable g77'. Scipy recommends using Anaconda. I have downloaded Anaconda, but cannot see how to download Numpy and Scipy using it. Also, apparently, I can use Macports, for which I need Xcode, and I have tried downloading Xcode twice and it won't open - the reviews say the new version is buggy.
Thus, what is the most conventional and effective way to install these tools? Did Anaconda automatically install Numpy and Scipy?

Comment: Try importing numpy (or those other libraries) and see if it works.  I believe Anaconda does by default install those libs.  If not, look at anaconda documentation to see how to install libraries.

Comment: Anaconda will give you everything you mentioned with much more. It also makes it easy to keep it all up to date. See https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of scientific distribution very well done today.For exemple, [pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org)
is a very nice and modern plug and play system for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) for installing Python packages.

> pip is the preferred installer program

`pip install numpy scipy pandas sklearn`